# Find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $\mathbf{C}= \left[\begin{array}{r r r} 4&6&2\\6&0&3\\2&3&-1 \end{array}\right]$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of
> $$\mathbf{C}= \left[\begin{array}{r r r} 4&6&2\\6&0&3\\2&3&-1
> \end{array}\right]$$

I found the the eigenvalues and are equal to $8.33, -6.63$ and $1.30.$ When I solve $(\lambda \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{C})\mathbf{E}=0$ I get the trivial solution as an answer while I shouldn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Of course taking $E$ trivial, that is, $E = 0$, gives $0 = 0$.  Can you find an *other* solution for each eigenvalue?  Also, there may be a typo in your matrix, the one shown here has eigenvalues $9.43{\dots}$, $-1.57{\dots}$, and $-4.85{\dots}$.

Comment: Where are those $ 8.33, -6.63$ and $1.30$ decimal values coming from? How are you solving the equation to find the eigen vectors?

Comment: I solved the characteristic equation $\lambda^3-3\lambda^2-53\lambda+72=0$, Matlab gives your answers, but when you do it manually you get different answers than Matlab

Comment: The characteristic equation is not the one you have written.  You have the sign of the constant coefficient flipped: "$\dots - 72$".

Comment: $(\lambda - 4) \begin{array}{|r r |} \lambda &3\\ 3&\lambda +1\end{array}- 6\begin{array}{|r r |} 6&3\\2&\lambda +1\end{array} +2\begin{array}{|r r |} 6&\lambda\\2&3\end{array}=(\lambda - 4) \big[\lambda (\lambda+1)-9\big]-6\big[ 6(\lambda+1)-6)\big]+2\big[18-2\lambda \big]$

Comment: @Diana When calculating the determinant of $\lambda I - C$, you forgot to invert the signs of all elements of $C$

Comment: O.k. I fixed that, but I'm getting the trivial solution when I evaluate the Eigen vectors $\left[ \begin{array}{r r r} 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1
\end{array}\right] =0$

Comment: Sum of the eigenvalues should equal the trace of the matrix, here the trace is $4+0-1=3$

Comment: Characteristic equation is $$-\lambda ^3+3 \lambda ^2+53 \lambda +72=0$$
which has the set of solutions
$$(-4.85851,-1.57151,9.43002)$$
and eigenvalues are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 2.42418 & 1.86055 & 1 \\
 1.1767 & -2.07064 & 1 \\
 -0.545324 & 0.173046 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

We are given the matrix

$$\mathbf{C}= \left[\begin{array}{r r r} 4&6&2\\6&0&3\\2&3&-1
\end{array}\right]$$

Find the characteristic polynomial using $|\lambda I - C|=0$ or $|C - \lambda I|=0$, just be consistent

$$|\lambda I - C| = \left|\begin{array}{r r r} \lambda-4&-6&-2\\-6&\lambda&-3\\-2&-3&\lambda+1\end{array}\right|$$

Use the Laplace expansion to write

$$(\lambda - 4)~ \begin{array}{|r r |} \lambda &-3\\ -3&\lambda +1\end{array}+ 6~\begin{array}{|r r |} -6&-3\\-2&\lambda +1\end{array} -2~\begin{array}{|r r |} -6&\lambda\\-2&-3\end{array}=\lambda^3 - 3 \lambda^2-53 \lambda - 72$$

The roots are

$$\lambda_{1,2,3} = 9.430018403873884, -1.5715091919701965, -4.858509211903689$$

For the eigenvectors, we solve $[\lambda I-C]v_i = 0$ using [*RREF*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form), so for $9.430018403873884$, we have

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & -2.424177326987695 \\
 0 & 1 & -1.860554583299498 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)v_1 = 0$$

If you want to see steps, you can use this [*RREF Calculator*](https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/linear-algebra/reduced-row-echelon-form-rref-caclulator/)

So, we have a free choice of $c$ and will choose $c = 1$, so $$v_1 = (2.424177326987695, 1.860554583299498, 1)$$

Repeat this process for the other two eigenvalues and find

$$v_2 = (-0.545323960202366, 0.17304624281151228, 1)\\v_3 = (1.176702188770226, -2.070637863148047, 1)$$